# Why should I choose features or plot them manually when there are built-in functions to do that?

Tags: feature-selection

- Why should I select variables due to my intuition if there are builtin functions in sklearn python like SelectKBest() and PCA()
- If I plot graphs of features of the data to see if they can detect the pattern of my categorical response:
  does that mean that I should plot hundreds and thousands of scatter plots?

Additional question:

- In my analysis I created a variable resulting from the product of 2 variables. This variable gives nice performance
  but if I use the log() of this variable it gives me an even better performance.
  I don't understand completely why taking the log of that variable resulted in a better perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are great and can help a lot, but computers do what you say, which is not necessarily the same as doing what you want. You need to know your data, your methods, your questions, your goals, your theory, because in the end it is you, and not the computer, who will be held responsible for what you say and write.

I don't know why you decided to take the log of a variable. There are many good reasons and many wrong reasons why one might do so. It all depends on the situation. However, I can give you advise on how to prevent this from happening in future. In order to do good research you need to keep a research log. This is a "diary" in which you document why you did the things you did. A normal research project involves making an awful lot of small decisions, like in your case taking the log of a variable. When you document your decisions when you make them, you won't end up in the situation you are in now.

Comment: i agree with you, i should know why i took my decisions in my report of analysis, but taking the log gives better performance, i just changed the scale of 1 variable ,i does not hurt the interpretation of my result

Answer (score 0):

Because you have something the computer does not have: a lot more real world training data in your mind.

You will see correlation which are not possible to a computer to see. Imagine a timescale. Holidays, for example, or events like Easter, which can lead to easy explainable correlations.

It's like using a navigation system: Sure, you can basically trust it. But would you trust it *blindly*? You know, they sometimes have strange routes which you will recognize. On the other hand, the computer has the ability to calculate optimized routes very fast. Combine those two abilities;)